# Auto mail merge using Automator, Filemaker, Word and Mail

Tags: macos, ms-word, filemaker, automator, mailmerge

I am using a mac and..
I want to know if it is possible to set up some automator scripts that

1. search a filemaker database for contacts who match a certain criteria and then
2. Save these contacts in a merge file (using export dialog).
3. open this file in ms word for mac and create all the mail merges for this file
4. finally send these mail merges out using mail.
5. (optional) i would like to specify how many emails can be sent out for a specific amount of time (i.e. maximum 500 emails sent per hour OR maximum 400 emails sent per day). this is to prevent my email accounts from being blocked for the rest of the day.. Gmail and others tend to have send limits and if i go over i cant send emails for the rest of the day :(

mainly want to know if this is possible using automator.. i understand that maybe id need to make 4/5 scripts and then 1 script that calls all 4/5 scripts in order??
any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you want to export data from FileMaker to MS Word which will then get emailed out. You can use FileMaker to do all of this.

While FileMaker doesn't support HTML emails, it does support attachments and has email functionality.

If you need HTML then look at Dacons MailIt or the 360 Works Email plugin.

Via a FileMaker script you can easily create a loop to send X records in a batch, or maintain a "start" time to throttle email sending.